# C# create new collection from two collections

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I would like to remove already used items from a list to populate a dropdown list

```
private void SetAvailableCodes(IEnumerable<ProductCodeVm> productCodes)
{
    var availableCodes = from item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(ProductCodeType))
                         where item != ProductCodeType.None.ToString()
                         select new
                         {
                             Id = (int)((ProductCodeType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ProductCodeType), item)),
                             Name = item
                         };
    // Todo remove productCodes.ProductCodeType 
    this.ViewData["CodeList"] = availableCodes;
}

public class ProductCodeVm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public int ProductId { get; set; }        
    public ProductCodeType ProductCodeType { get; set; }     <--- Enum  
    public string Value { get; set; }       
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this using linq, or do I need to do some casting, or something else?

Available codes comes from Db

```
// Add codes
var codes = ProductCodeManager.GetByProductId(model.Id);
model.ProductCodes =
codes.Select(
    c =>
    new ProductCodeVm
    {
        ProductCodeType = c.ProductCodeType,
        Value = c.Value,
        ProductCodeId = c.ProductCodeId
    });
this.SetAvailableCodes(model.ProductCodes);
```

The available codes is only used to populate dropdownlist(id,name)

```
this.ViewData["CodeList"] = availableCodes;
```

Comment: Do you want to remove or just now show them, also, what do you mean by "already used", you mean you just want unique list out of the procutCodes?

Comment: How do you define whether item is already used?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Except()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

```
IEnumerable<string> remainingList = allItemsList.Except(usedItemList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `productCodes` is the list of codes to filter out, it will be easier to filter on *values* instead of *strings* so you don;t have as much parsing to do:

```
var availableCodes = 
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProductCodeType))
        .Except((int)ProductCodeType.None)
        .Except(productCodes.Select( p => p.Id)
        .Select(p => new {
                              Id = p;
                              Name = ((ProductCodeType)p).ToString();
                         }
```